# How to change magento 2.1.1 Registration success message?

Tags: magento-2.1

Can you help me on how to modify the default success message like "Thank you for your registration" after you create an account or register an account in magento 2.1.1.

Answer (score 4):

Create your own theme ( please check this link for create theme : http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html ) and in that create below file :

```
{Magento root}\app\design\frontend\{Your Vendor}\ {Your theme}\Magento_Customer\i18n\en_US.csv
```

in `en_US.csv` file add your own message :

```
"Thank you for registering with %1.","Thank you for your registration."
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for your answer. I really appreciate this I'll try this first.

Comment: I have a question. I followed your instructions but still the same the success message is is still the same.

Comment: please clear cache and also run this command php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: Thanks I'll try again with the one you suggest. sorry I forgot to do that earlier.

Comment: This didn't seem to work for me in Magento 2.2.1 - anyone else have issue?

Comment: Perfect Answer!!! +1 made my day :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to override controller file in your module.

```
vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Account/CreatePost.php
```

After overrider above file changes in getSuccessMessage() function,
You can change your message in below functiom.

Path for di.xml file,
**app/code/Vendor/Modulename/etc/frontend/**

**di.xml file,**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost"
                type="Vendor\Modulename\Controller\Account\CreatePost" />
</config>
```

Path for controller override,
**Vendor\Modulename\Controller\Account**

CreatePost.php file

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Modulename\Controller\Account;

class CreatePost extends \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost{   
    protected function getSuccessMessage()
    {
        if ($this->addressHelper->isVatValidationEnabled()) {
            if ($this->addressHelper->getTaxCalculationAddressType() == Address::TYPE_SHIPPING) {
                // @codingStandardsIgnoreStart
                $message = __(
                    'If you are a registered VAT customer, please <a href="%1">click here</a> to enter your shipping address for proper VAT calculation.',
                    $this->urlModel->getUrl('customer/address/edit')
                );
                // @codingStandardsIgnoreEnd
            } else {
                // @codingStandardsIgnoreStart
                $message = __(
                    'If you are a registered VAT customer, please <a href="%1">click here</a> to enter your billing address for proper VAT calculation.',
                    $this->urlModel->getUrl('customer/address/edit')
                );
                // @codingStandardsIgnoreEnd
            }
        } else {
         //your custom message...
            $message = __('Thank you for registering with us');
        }
        return $message;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Rakesh, Thanks for this I'll try this first

Comment: Have you try with this?

Comment: upgrade,compile,deploy are required

Comment: Not working I m trying this

Answer (score 1):

di.xml:

```
<preference for="Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatPost"
            type="<namespace>\<module_name>\Controller\Account\CreatPost" />
```

Override controller method(Magento\Customer\Controller\Account):

```
/**
 * Retrieve success message
 *
 * @return string
 */
protected function getSuccessMessage()
{
    if ($this->addressHelper->isVatValidationEnabled()) {
        if ($this->addressHelper->getTaxCalculationAddressType() == Address::TYPE_SHIPPING) {
            // @codingStandardsIgnoreStart
            $message = __(
                'If you are a registered VAT customer, please <a href="%1">click here</a> to enter your shipping address for proper VAT calculation.',
                $this->urlModel->getUrl('customer/address/edit')
            );
            // @codingStandardsIgnoreEnd
        } else {
            // @codingStandardsIgnoreStart
            $message = __(
                'If you are a registered VAT customer, please <a href="%1">click here</a> to enter your billing address for proper VAT calculation.',
                $this->urlModel->getUrl('customer/address/edit')
            );
            // @codingStandardsIgnoreEnd
        }
    } else {
        $message = __('Thank you for registering with %1.', $this->storeManager->getStore()->getFrontendName());
    }
    return $message;
}
```

Comment: Hello Ronak, Thank you for your answer also. I'll try your approach also thanks again

Comment: @ronak this is not proper method we can do this with the help of translation

Comment: Translation is another way to do so, but This is proper method to override anything of core module.

Comment: Ok Ronak, I'll try also your approach. I'll feedback later if it will really work in my end. Thanks

Comment: my pleasure brother. Happy to help. @MazeStricks

Comment: It did not work for me.

Comment: have you checked that you are able to override controller or not?

Answer (score 0):

I am using Magento 2.4.5p1 latest version & following approach works fine for me.

**Step 1:** Create an i18n folder & an en_US.csv file under your custom theme.

> File Path: app/design/frontend/Your Vendor/your theme
> name/i18n/en_US.csv

**Step 2:** In the en_US.csv file add the below translation. I have added a translation for the customer register success message. Please note, I have mentioned **"module"** keyword & **actual module name** to inform Magento regarding our custom translation.

> "You must confirm your account. Please check your email for the
> confirmation link or <a href=""%1"">click here for a new
> link.","You must confirm your account. Please check your email for the
> confirmation link or <a href=""%1"">click here for a new link.
> Please check your spam if the email is not
> received.",module,Magento_Customer,

**Step 3:** Clear cache & check. If still not reflecting clear static content deploy & check.

If your Magento has multiple language setups, create respected translations using the above first step. I have made a nb_NO.csv file as well for the Norwegian language.

> "You must confirm your account. Please check your email for the
> confirmation link or <a href=""%1"">click here for a new
> link.","Du må bekrefte kontoen din. Vennligst sjekk e-posten din for
> bekreftelseslenken eller <a href=""%1"">klikk her for en ny lenke.
> Vennligst sjekk spam hvis e-posten ikke er
> mottatt.",module,Magento_Customer,

If you want to translate any theme text to other languages, add the line below. In my case Norwegian language(nb_NO.csv). Clear cache & check.

> "SHIPPING
> ADDRESS:","SENDINGSADRESSE:","theme","frontend/Your Vendor/your theme name",