# How to modify/update cart success message in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, overrides, messages

I want to modify/update the success message added by cart controller (`Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add`).

As described [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/145262/23943) and [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/86501), I can use `preference` to override controller to update success message but I think overriding core classes is bad idea.

So, is there any other better way to update success message instead of preference?

Comment: You could use translation files to change message. Place the changed message in language translation file under i18n directory.

Comment: thanks for solution but it won't work in a case when I want to add some dynamic information with success message.. For example, URL of cart page..

Comment: In case you want to add dynamic information also you need to use plugin/preference only according to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use plugin or event/observer to update the success message. In my case, I used postdispatch event.

> app/code/{Vendor}/{Module}/etc/frontend/events.xml

```
<event name="controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_cart_add">
    <observer name="updatemessage" instance="{Vendor}\{Module}\Observer\UpdateMessage" />
</event>
```

In observer, Use `\Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface` to get last added message and add new/updated success message.

> app/code/{Vendor}/{Module}/Observer/UpdateMessage.php

```
<?php
namespace {Vendor}\{Module}\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

class UpdateMessage implements ObserverInterface
{
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface */
    protected $messageManager;

    /** @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface */
    protected $url;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $managerInterface,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url
    ) {
        $this->messageManager = $managerInterface;
        $this->url = $url;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
        $messageCollection = $this->messageManager->getMessages(true);
        $cartLink = '<a href="'. $this->url->getUrl('checkout/cart') .'">View Cart/Checkout</a>';
        $this->messageManager->addSuccess($messageCollection->getLastAddedMessage()->getText() . '  ' . $cartLink);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I was searching for solution via plugin, but observer is also working fine..

Comment: @Shyam, is that possible to do this using plugins instead of observer ?

Comment: @Camit1dk Yes, it is possible. You can use `afterExecute()` to do the same

Comment: Thanks Shyam , What can i used in return value while using plugin ?

Comment: @Shyam, can you please answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/246296/how-to-update-success-error-message-using-plugin-in-magento-2, since you have mentioned that it is possible to do the same using plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the Add to cart message from the following template file.

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/message/addCartSuccessMessage.phtml
```

> Note: Do not make any changes in core files. Override this template
>   file in your theme and make changes there.