# How to update success/error message using PLUGIN in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, plugin, success-message, error-message

I have already checked this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/155826/how-to-modify-update-cart-success-message-in-magento-2) and found it working, but in this thread, the observer is used to change the success/error message.

I want to know whether it is possible to **change/update** the **success/error** message using a **plugin** or not?

If it is possible, then please let me know how?

I also know how to use translation way to change messages.

I have tried many ways but could not get success.